# How to remove certain data from a string?

Tags: python, string

This code outputs the timestamp and odds for a particular horse. I want to remove the timestamp from the output of the code.

My code:

```
request2 = requests.get('https://www.punters.com.au/api/web/public/Odds/getOddsComparisonCacheable/?allowGet=true&APIKey=65d5a3e79fcd603b3845f0dc7c2437f0&eventId=1045618&betType=FixedWin', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
json2 = request2.json()
for selection in json2['selections']:
    for fluc in selection['flucs'][0]:
        data = ast.literal_eval(selection['flucs'])
        print(data[-2:])
```

Output of code:

```
[[1598060018, 12.97], [1598060095, 13.13]]
[[1598060066, 4.41], [1598060095, 4.36]]
[[1598060030, 2.11], [1598060095, 2.12]]
[[1598060030, 5.69], [1598060095, 5.61]]
[[1598059986, 16.35], [1598060095, 16.6]]
[[1598060006, 12.06], [1598060095, 12.35]]
[[1598060026, 25.83], [1598060095, 26.25]]
[[1598060026, 39.25], [1598060095, 39.83]]
```

Desired output of code:

```
[[12.97], [13.13]]
[[4.41], [4.36]]
[[2.11], [2.12]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below

```
data = [[1598060018, 12.97], [1598060095, 13.13]]
new_data = [[x[1]] for x in data]
print(new_data)
```

output

```
[[12.97], [13.13]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for lsst in new data:
    a=[str(item) for item in lsst if "." not in lsst]
```

or

```
if type==float:
    "keep it"
else:
    "remove .. delete whatever"
```